# Dollar sign "$" is removed from secret values in Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

Creating a new Azure Databricks secret with dollar sign in value e.g. `abc$_a`. The secret is injected as env variable to cluster. Dollar sign is removed from the value that Spark job receives e.g. `abc_a`. Using the `/api/2.0/secrets/put` API.

[Similar problem](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/incorrect-secret-value-when-loaded-as-environment-variable/td-p/21820) was reported in databricks community, but the post has no resolution yet.

Tried to use `bytes_value` instead of `string_value` - same result.

Answer (score 0):

Will answer myself on found solution: the dollar sign can be escaped with double backslash:

```
{
    "scope": "my_scope",
    "key": "my_password",
    "string_value": "abc\\$_a"
}
```

This is due to secrets are injected with `export my_password=abc$_a` so that dollar is treated something related to variable and replaced by shell.
Hope will be useful.